# In webpack, how can I have different output directories for multiple entry points?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have the following webpack configuration with multiple entry points...

```
module.exports = {
 entry: {
  somePage: "./scripts/someDir/somePage.js",
  anotherPage: "./scripts/someDir/someSubDir/anotherPage.js"
 },
 output: {
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out'),
   filename: '[name].js'
 },
 ...
```

Is it possible to set a different output path for each entry?

Instead of getting an output of...

`/out/somePage.js
/out/anotherPage.js`

I want...

`/out/someDir/somePage.js
/out/someDir/someSubDir/anotherPage.js`

The ideal solution for me would be for `output.path` to accept a function. For example...

```
...
output: {
   path: function (name, hash) {
       return path.resolve(__dirname, myMapOfFilenamesToDirs[name]);
   },
   filename: '[name].js'
},
```

Does anyone know if this is possible or if there is an existing plugin that can accomplish this?

**EDIT** I don't want to use multiple config entries (multi-compiler) because I won't be able to create a shared file among the entry points with CommonsChunkPlugin anymore

Comment: Did you tried renaming anotherPage in "someSubDir/anotherPage" (using the `"`) in your entry object ?

Comment: I had tried send the second parameter in path.resolve as 'build/[name]/', turned out Webpack wouldn't compile. But the best answer below really works like charm.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A bit hacky, but this should do the trick.

```
module.exports = {
 entry: {
  "somePage": "./scripts/someDir/somePage.js",
  "someSubDir/anotherPage": "./scripts/someDir/someSubDir/anotherPage.js"
 },
 output: {
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out/someDir'),
   filename: '[name].js'
 },
 // Etc.
}
```

You cannot set the path to a function, webpack won't call it for you.

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense. Great solution.

Comment: This is genius!

Comment: Wow, this is absolute geniousness ! I was getting frustrated about webpack for not letting me define output path as function(ideally to achieve different output paths). This works so perfectly that I am not even sure to call it a hack.

Comment: For people who are wondering whats different in the solution from the question like I did, He is manipulating the entry filename from just the file name to filename with the required path.

Comment: Best part is, entry takes a function so you can even automate this instead of manually entering the paths !!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working for chunks but entries.

Comment: output property is not loger supported by vue.js 3

Answer (score 3):

You can return an array of configurations for webpack to execute. I think that will give you enough control over the output path to achieve what you need.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I can no longer create a shared bundle among the different entry points using the CommonsChunkPlugin or a shared stylesheet with the ExtractTextPlugin. Are you are aware of some way to accomplish this with multiple configs?

Comment: @CharlieMartin You can do `[name]/[name].js` but obviously that's not what you want. It's likely you'll need to patch webpack yourself to make it work.

Comment: @bebraw *patch webpack yourself* haha

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today, adding on to the answer from @quentin-roy, https://stackoverflow.com/a/33086806/6552940

You can also create the output path mappings for input files using `glob` and the following callback. Adjust your `glob` pattern according to your needs. The following pattern and callback if applied on the directory structure

```sh
- src
   - file01.ts
   lib
     - file02.ts
```

will result in

```sh
- dist
   - file01.js
   lib
     - file02.js
```

```
config = {
    entry: () => {
        const entries = {};
        glob.sync("./src/**/*.ts").forEach(filePath => {
            entries[
                path
                    .relative("./src", filePath)
                    .replace(path.extname(filePath), "")
            ] = filePath;
        });
        console.debug(
            `Entries created:\n${JSON.stringify(entries, undefined, 4)}`,
        );
        return entries;
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some evaluations I'm using the [Webpack-watched-glob-entries-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-watched-glob-entries-plugin) for some time, because it is small, does what we need and works also in watch mode.

If you need even more ideas take a look here [Wildcards in entry points](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/370).